# Unable to get email address onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="divForm" class="fancybox" style="display:none;">
    <form id="frm_step1" action="download1.php" method="post">
        <label>Enter Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" required />
        <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="form-submit" target-form="frm_step1" onclick="test();" />
    </form>
</div>
```

```js
function test() {
    var email = $('#email').text();
    alert(email);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'download1.php?email' + email,
        data: { 'email': email },
        success: function(data) {
            window.location.href = 'download.php#file';
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
    });
}
```

I am not able to get email from this. When I put alert it returns blank.
And I always use jQuery/AJAX like this but this time it does not alert email address.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.val()` instead of `.text()`. The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as **input**, **select** and **textarea**.

```
$('#email').val();
```

```js
function test() {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    alert(email);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'download1.php?email' + email,
        data: { 'email': email },
        success: function(data) {
            window.location.href = 'download.php#file';
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divForm" class="fancybox">
    <form id="frm_step1" action="download1.php" method="post">
        <label>Enter Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" required />
        <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="form-submit" target-form="frm_step1" onclick="test();" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: first time i used val() only, but still getting same error.

Comment: i am not getting any error, but i am also not getting email, just return blank.

Comment: what u did, u run same code or your own.

Comment: i do not understand what to do, very confused.

Comment: yes i did everything, but you know what the error is coming through popup, if you simply run this it will be fine.

Comment: in your case the textbox is hidden defaulty? I remove the line style="display:none;" from the div class fancybox